# Qt Stylesheets: How to apply style to menus? How to remove blue tinge around QTextEdit?

Tags: qt4.7, qmenu, qtstylesheets, qmenubar

I am trying to make the menubar a gradient black colour and that works fine, except for the menu headings.

Here's the stylesheet i'm using:

```
 QString styleSheet = "QMenuBar{background: qlineargradient(x1:0,x2:0,y1:0,y2:1,stop:0 #cccccc, stop:0.4 gray)} QStatusBar{background: qlineargradient(x1:0,x2:0,y1:0,y2:1,stop:0 #cccccc, stop:0.4 gray);color:white;} ";

this->setStyleSheet(styleSheet);
```

1. How do I apply the style to the meny headings too?
2. There is a blue tinge all around the `QTextEdit` which I can't get rid of. Is there a way to set it to black?

Thanks :)

[image: stylesheet not applied to menu items]

Comment: http://www.trinitydesktop.org/docs/qt4/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qmenubar

Comment: nmagerko - that link was really useful. Could you please write as the answer so that I can accept it. Second, it doesn't quite answer how to get rid of the blue tinge - do you have any idea about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. for aply color to the headings:

   ```
   QMenuBar::item{
       background-color: qlineargradient(x1:0,x2:0,y1:0,y2:1,stop:0 #cccccc, stop:0.4 gray)
   }
   ```
2. For the blue tinge all around the `QTextEdit`:

   ```
   QTextEdit{
       border: 0
   `
   ```

Answer (score 6):

I believe that the following website is a good resource for answering your question about the QT `menubar` issue you are having:

http://www.trinitydesktop.org/docs/qt4/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qmenubar

It gives a few code samples which should fully explain what you need to know. As for the blue tinge, I do not have a good idea on how to fix it - I haven't really seen that happen.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 2):

This solved the problem for me:

```
QMenuBar::item {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `QMenuBar::item{}`.